K3 surfaces and density of rational curves
A smooth, complex, projective surface, such that the canonical bundle is trivial and the irregularity is equal to zero is called a K3 surface.  Recently I received feedback regarding work I had done.  In my work I had assumed that if $ M $ was a variety which was not uniruled, then I assumed that it was possible to find an open neighborhood $ U \subseteq M $ such that $ U $ did not intersect any rational curve of $ M $ non-trivially.
I received an email from someone who had read this work in which they said that this was not always possible for a K3 surface.
I later found a paper by Fedor Bogomolov, Brendan Hasset and Yuri Tschinkel in which the authors of this paper proved that for a very general K3 surface with Picard group generated by a class of degree two, there are an infinite number of rational curves.  So it seemed like the input I was given that it might not be possible to find an open sub-variety of a K3 surface which did not intersect any rational curves non-trivially could be true.
Let $ W $ be the set of points of a K3 surface $ S $ which are not contained in a rational curve and let $ \overline{W} $ be its closure.  If $ W $ is not dense in $ S $ there should be a dominant, rational map $ \phi: \mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}} \times \operatorname{Mor}(\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}},S) \dashrightarrow S $ since any point of $ S \setminus \overline{W} $ is contained in a rational curve.  So there should be a curve $ C $ contained in $ \operatorname{Mor}(\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}},S) $ such that $ \phi: \mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}} \times C \dashrightarrow S $ is generically finite and dominant.  This would mean that $ S $ is uniruled.  However, the genus of a uniruled variety over a field of characteristic zero vanishes, while the genus of a K3 surface is one.  Can anyone tell me what the error is in this p"r"oof that for any K3 surface there is an open sub-variety which does not intersect a rational curve non-trivially?

Maybe someone told you that K3s can have a dense set of rational curves, but didn't say, or didn't mean to say, that the set was an open subvariety?

Anyway, it is better to say where you learned that from.

That is definitely not true over $\mathbb{C}$.  Maybe they meant "entire curves" rather than "rational curves".  It is true over fields of positive characteristic that there are unirational K3 surfaces.

Thank you @Sasha.  I have added this detail to the post.

Thank you @JasonStarr.  The individual did mean rational curves.  I wrote down a more exact description of what was said because the original phrasing of the question was inadequate.

Your argument in the last paragraph seems to assume that any dense subset of $S$ contains a nonempty open set. That is not true.

I know that if $ W $ is a constructible set, then $ W $ would contain a nonempty open set by a theorem of Chevalley.  I had forgotten that the constructible hypothesis is necessary.  If the set of rational curves of a K3 surface is not constructible, then that would be an error in the argument.  Thank you @LazzaroCampeotti.  I am going to add a question regarding this detail to this site if no one answers in the comments.  If I or you find out that $ W $ is not known to be constructible, then please add your comment as an answer and I will gladly upvote it.

Yes $W$ is not constructible. Over the complex numbers, the dense set of rational curves is a countable union of rational curves. Countable unions of closed subsets are not constructible in general so the complement $W$ is also not constructible. In particular, every Zariski open set meets infinitely many of these rational curves. This is a reflection of the fact that Zariski opens are very large (analogous say to the fact that every Zariski open set of $\mathbb{P}^1$ contains countably many points with integer coordinates so this set is dense even though it is a countable union of closeds).

Thank you @DoriBejleri.  I appreciate you answering that question.

@LazzaroCampeotti, please add your comment as an answer.  I will vote it as correct.  Thank you to everyone who commented.  This broadened my understanding.

The OP requested that I add my comment as an answer:

Your argument in the last paragraph seems to assume that any dense subset of $S$ contains a nonempty open set. That is not true.

Specifically in this case, if $S$ is a $K3$ surface with infinitely many rational curves, and if $W \subset S$ is the complement of the union of all rational curves, then $W$ is dense but it does not contain any nonempty open set. The last claim is easy to see: If $U \subset W$ were a nonempty open set, then the complement $S \setminus U$ would be a proper closed subset of $S$, therefore of dimension at most 1, and since a closed set has finitely many components, $S \setminus U$ could contain at most finitely many curves.

Rational curves are dense on K3 for all K3 outside of a Baire set
(countable union of closed, nowhere dense). Here is the reference:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5167, Density of Rational Curves on K3 Surfaces,
Xi Chen, James D. Lewis
